# AppEngine Initial Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a python application that I've been running with the devserver and everything seems to work fine except I am having problems initializing my datastore. Basically I need to set up data store values from a bunch of files that are on my local drive, but I don't want to upload go google. I set up a simple python script inside my app directory that does all of the data creation, but now I'm having a lot of problems deploying my app. How do I get a dump of the data that dev_appserver is using and upload it to my application?

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 1):

Download the data using appcfg.py (after enabling the remote_api), then re-'upload' it to local devappserver.

http://blog.mfabrik.com/2011/03/14/mirroring-app-engine-production-data-to-development-server-using-appcfg-py/

Comment: This page is no longer available :-(